# Incidence matrix instead of adjacency matrix

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, graph, big-o

What kind of problems on graphs is faster (in terms of big-O) to solve using incidence matrix data structures instead of more widespread adjacency matrices?

Comment: I'm not confident that it's easy to find a computational upper-bound based on the underlying representation.  Most of the algorithmic complexity will be in terms of the _number_ of edges or vertices, not the underlying representation.  Any lower-bound on complexity is going to apply whether it's implemented on pencil and paper or on a computer.  Is think if there are specific classes of problems you have in mind, then maybe mention those and we can try to figure it out?

Comment: Incidence matrix is MxN and adjacency matrix is NxN if N is very large and your graph is very sparse you'll have MxN < NxN.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The space complexities of the structures are:

Adjacency: O(V^2)
Incidence: O(VE)

With the consequence that an incidence structure saves space if there are many more vertices than edges.

You can look at the time complexity of some typical graph operations:

Find all vertices adjacent to a vertex:
Adj: O(V)
Inc: O(VE)

Check if two vertices are adjacent:
Adj: O(1)
Inc: O(E)

Count the valence of a vertex:
Adj: O(V)
Inc: O(E)

And so on. For any given algorithm, you can use building blocks like the above to calculate which representation gives you better overall time complexity.

As a final note, using a matrix of any kind is extremely space-inefficient for all but the most dense of graphs, and I recommend against using either unless you've consciously dismissed alternatives like adjacency lists.

Comment: I have very dense graphs, with almost every-to-every connections.

Comment: Aren't there ways to efficiently store sparse matrix?

Answer (score 4):

I personally have never found a real application of the incidence matrix representation in a programming contest or research problem. I think that is may be useful for proving some theorems or for some very special problems. One book gives an example of "counting the number of spanning trees" as a problem in which this representation is useful.

Another issue with this representation is that it makes no sense to store it, because it is really easy to compute it dynamically (to answer what given cell contains) from the list of edges.

It may seem more useful in hyper-graphs however, but only if it is dense.

So my opinion is - it is useful only for theoretical works.